# RNFIREBASE MESSENGER not working on iOS but working on Android

Tags: ios, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

Push notifications are working on Android but not iOS. I have tested on a device and through Test flight as simulator isn't supported

I have done the additional setup required for iOS.

Below is relevant info in my package.json file

Package.json

```
  "name": "####",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "*",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "*",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "*",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "*",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "*",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "*",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "*",
    "prop-types": "*",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.63.4",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "*",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "*",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.0.0-alpha",
    "react-native-render-html": "*",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "*",
    "react-native-screens": "*",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.7.1",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.11.1",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.8.4",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^1.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^25.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^25.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.59.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Included in index.js where I have adde the respective react-native-firebase code snippets

```
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
// Register background handler
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
  console.log('Hey');
  console.log('Message handled in the background!', remoteMessage);
});

const Applicaiton: () => React$Node = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('RN Message Called on USEFFECT!');
    const unsubscribe = messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {
      Alert.alert('A new FCM message arrived!', JSON.stringify(remoteMessage));
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);


async function requestUserPermission() {
    const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();
    const enabled =
      authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED ||
      authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL;
  
    if (enabled) {
      console.log('Authorization status:', authStatus);
    }
  }
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <Firebase.h>
#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>


@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  
   if ([FIRApp defaultApp] == nil) {
     [FIRApp configure];
   }
  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                   moduleName:@"appName"
                                            initialProperties:nil];
```

Xcode target output which is flagging some issues with Firebase

```
2021-08-27 11:23:39.606662-0400 appName[69219:5588124] 8.1.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000003] The default Firebase app has not yet been configured. Add `[FIRApp configure];` "(`FirebaseApp.configure()`" in Swift) to your application initialization. Read more:
2021-08-27 11:23:39.700654-0400 appName[69219:5588429] 8.1.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM001000] FIRMessaging Remote Notifications proxy enabled, will swizzle remote notification receiver handlers. If you'd prefer to manually integrate Firebase Messaging, add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist, and set it to NO. Follow the instructions at:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#method_swizzling_in_firebase_messaging
to ensure proper integration.
2021-08-27 11:23:39.706694-0400 appName[69219:5588429] 8.1.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.8.1.0 started
2021-08-27 11:23:39.751967-0400 appName[69219:5588429] 8.1.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see )
2021-08-27 11:23:39.799721-0400 appName[69219:5578599] [native] Running application appName ({
    initialProps =     {
    };
    rootTag = 1;
})
```

Signing and Certificates
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firebase Messaging on ios needs more configuration,

first, you need to add this import in AppDelegate.m:
 `#import "RNFBMessagingModule.h"`

then after this line: `RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];`

add this line: `NSDictionary *appProperties = [RNFBMessagingModule addCustomPropsToUserProps:nil withLaunchOptions:launchOptions];`

then you need to change the **initialProperties** in the **RCTRootView** from `nil` into `appProperties` so it will be like this:

`RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge moduleName:@"RETUЯИ" initialProperties:appProperties];`  <-- changed from nil into appProperties

After all, we need to add an **APNs Authentication Key** file in the firebase console.

go to project setting, then scroll down to see your ios app, you will see **APNs Authentication Key** title, you need to upload an authKey.p8 file or you can use the other two fields with the title  **APNs Certificates**

the authKey.p8 file needs to be generated from **app store connect**

- Select Users and Access, and then select the API Keys tab. // ***see the update section*** ⏬⏬⏬
- Click Generate API Key or the Add (+) button.
- Give a name to your key, tick the "Apple Push Notifications Service" box, and download
- Upload the .p8 file to the firebase console

---

> **Update regarding authkey.p8:**

- you need to generate it from the apple developer account, in the auth
  keys list, this is the [link](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/authkeys/list)
- [instructions](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage/ios-setup)

---

of course, don't miss to add the **GoogleService-info.plist** file to your example.xcworkspace, you can see how to do that in [rnfirebase.io](https://rnfirebase.io/#generating-ios-credentials)

also, you need your Team id, and you can get it from the app store connect profile and you will see the key id after generateing it.

hope this will help you ,

Regards

Comment: i dont understand why your app delegate is different from mine. where is this in the documentation?